# How can i programatically send contact us mail in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, contact-us, contact-form

i have tried using the below code but didn't get the solution.

```
public function contactUs()
  {
     //$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

     //$mail = new Zend_Mail();
     $this->mail->setTemplateVars('hHai ywyywn.');
     $this->mail->setFrom('testfrom@test.in', 'fayis');
     $this->mail->addTo('testto@test.in', 'Some Recipient');
     $this->mail->setSubject('Test contact us');
       try {
         $this->mail->send();
       }        
       catch(Exception $ex) {
          Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Inchoo_SimpleContact.');
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for my question.find the below code:

```
    public function contactUs($name,$email,$telephone,$comment)
   {
   // echo $name." ".$email." ".$telephone." ".$comment;exit;
     $result_arr = $this->_masterobj->getResultarray();
     $data = array('data'=>new DataObject([
                'name' => $name,
                'email' => $email,
                'telephone' => $telephone,
                'comment' => $comment
            ]));
  // print_r($data);exit;
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
        ->setTemplateVars(
           $data
        )
        ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
        // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> 
        General -> Store Email Addresses
        ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at how the Magento_Contact module handles the email sending you'll be able to use much of what they use.

First off inject `Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface` into your class through the constructor and use as `$this->mail`.

```
...

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface $mail
) {
    $this->mail = $mail;
}

...
```

Then use this to access the `send()` method. Something similar to below:

```
private function sendTheConatactEmail(array $data)
{
    $this->mail->send(
        $data['email'], 
        ['data' => new DataObject($data)]
    );
}
```

Looking below at the actual `send` method we call you can see how the `DataObject` is actually used:

```
/**
 * Send email from contact form
 *
 * @param string $replyTo
 * @param array $variables
 * @return void
 */
public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
{
    /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
    $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;

    $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
    try {
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                ]
            )
            ->setTemplateVars($variables)
            ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
            ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
            ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
    } finally {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }
}
```

An example of the `$data` array we could pass would be:

```
[
    'name' => 'Josh Carter',
    'email' => 'josh@carter.com',
    'telephone' => '12345678901'
    'comment' => 'I need some help so I filled in the contact form.'
]
```

Hope this helps.

Josh

Comment: Hi josh what are all the values i want to pass in $variables. i have passed like this but it doesnt set the 'values:   $variable= array('Name'=>'chris','Phone Number'=>'55555555','Email'=>'test@test.com','Comment'=>'tes comment');

Comment: Hi Christy, i've updated my answer now. Please note that PHP would be case sensitive when accessing the values and they will be trying to access to values with lowercase keys. My guess is that's what's up with your array.

Comment: No problem Christy, please kindly upvote my answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: Actually i have override contact post controller in custom module but m getting error with this function Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send()

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232501/contact-post-controller-overridden-in-custom-module-not-working/232504?noredirect=1#comment324097_232504